# How to widen PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot whose legend, when placed at the bottom, is two lines rather than one:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Abs /@ {Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]}, Below]]
```

If I do the same thing without the absolute value signs, it plots in a row as I'd like:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]}, Below]]
```

I'm guessing the absolute value signs make this slightly too wide, but putting the two legends side by side would clearly fit into the plot. I've spent a while digging through the documentation and cannot figure out how to do this - help would be appreciated!

Comment: nice to meet you here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be a bug. One can explicitly specify the layout of plot, for example,

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {Abs[Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1]], 
  Abs[Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]]}, 
 LegendLayout -> (Grid[{Flatten@#}] &)]
```

And here is the plotting function applying the above method:

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Abs@{Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1], 
      Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1] }, 
    LegendLayout -> (Grid[{Flatten@#}] &)], Below ]]
```

Answer (score 4):

### `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}`

The option `LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}` gives the desired result:

```
legend = LineLegend[Automatic, Abs /@ {Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1], 
     Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];

Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Below]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite satisfactory but at least a row:

```
row[p_] := 
 TableForm[p, TableAlignments -> Center, TableDirections -> Row]

leg :=
 LineLegend[{Orange, Blue},
  {TraditionalForm[Abs[Subscript[a, 2]/Subscript[a, 1]]],
   TraditionalForm[Abs[Subscript[a, 3]/Subscript[a, 1]]]},
  LegendLayout -> row]

Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> {0, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[leg, Below]]
```